# Wordpress on Fargate with ALB not working

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

So I've tried a couple of times with different Dockerfiles (which are succesfully pushed to ECR), but whenever I paste teh ALB DNS on the browser it shows this message[wordpress first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJQBg.png)

Like theres no wordpress choosing language neither initial config, so I assume theres something wrong because If I complete those fields, then the error is this one [wordpress error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM9uF.png)

Dockerfile i used:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
  
  # Install dependencies
  RUN apt-get update && \
     apt-get install -y libzip-dev && \
     docker-php-ext-install zip && \
      apt-get clean
  
  # Download and install WordPress
 RUN curl -O https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz && \
     tar xzvf latest.tar.gz && \
     rm latest.tar.gz && \
     mv wordpress/* /var/www/html/
```

Nothing seems to word despite the instalation is being done
I've used this material to install it: https://www.internetkatta.com/host-wordpress-on-aws-ecs-using-fargate

Any help will be much appreciated

Wordpress on fargate. Couldn't get to work

Comment: That tutorial is incomplete and fairly terrible. It walks you through a bunch of ECR setup when you don't need to do that at all for a public docker image, and in the disclaimer at the end it mentions that once you are finished with the tutorial you won't even have a database yet, so you won't be able to actually get past the setup page for WordPress. It also doesn't mention the fact that you have to use an AWS EFS volume if you are planning to run WordPress on Fargate. Please view the official documentation https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/running-wordpress-amazon-ecs-fargate-ecs/

Comment: Tried that method also, but CFN gets stucked and returns nothing..

Comment: That problem would be worth its own question on this site. Otherwise you need to take that tutorial you are looking at, and add an RDS database, and configure WordPress to use that database, and also add an EFS volume mapping into the Fargate container, so that any changes to any files (theme or plugin downloads, media uploads, etc.) actually get saved between container restarts.

Comment: I've managed to advance with the official documentation posted above. The thing is, when I have to create a TD with JSON, its just paste that code on my terminal? and the docker file with the Bitnami image, also create a dockerfile with it?

Comment: You'll need that JSON saved to a file, if you are doing this all from the command line. I actually don't recommend using the Bitnami image, but I guess that's what the official documentation uses. I recommend using the official WordPress image hosted on the public ECR repository: https://gallery.ecr.aws/docker/library/wordpress so you don't need to have your own ECR repo. And you don't need a `Dockerfile` at all unless you are making custom modifications to the docker iamge.

Comment: Oh I see. Will use the official image then. When you say download it to a file, it's only create a file.json and paste the content? I dont quite get how should I use that task definiton

Comment: Im able to create all infastructure usinf the image from ECR, but Im not able to register targets on TG. If I leave / or //wp-admin/setup-config.php, or /wordpress, does not register anything